# I want to fill my entire house with turnips, how many do I need to buy? How many trips do I need to make to Daisy Mae?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

Turnip storage is an issue. Anything left outside can be easily picked up by other players. Storing turnips on my floor at home is a much better option. I want to fill my house to capacity with turnips. How many turnips do I need to buy? How many trips to Daisy Mae do I need to make?

Answer (score 27):

**TLDR;** 29,200 / 292 bundles / 8 trips to Daisy Mae

---

We'll assume that your house is maxed out and that your pocket storage is also maxed out.

Here are the measurements of a maxed out home:

- Basement: 6x10 = 60

  > [image]
- Upstairs: 6x10 = 60

  > [image]
- Left-room: 6x6 = 36

  > [image]
- Right-room: 6x6 = 36

  > [image]
- Backroom: 6x6 = 36

  > [image]
- Front-room: 8x8 = 64

  > [image]

There are 292 floor spot in your house where you can put your turnips.

- You can carry 40 bundles of turnips.

  > [image]

Which is 4,000 turnips, as each bundle has 100 turnips in it. You will have 280 bundles of turnips after seven full trips to Daisy Mae; you'll need to make an eight trip to buy the extra 12 bundles.

Comment: Also, you can make it in the same number of trips (7 full and 1 partial) while keeping a pole vault and ladder in your inventory. 292 / 38 = ~7.68. In addition, you can do it with a third extra item (like a wand or something) and still make it in 8 trips but if you carry 4 things you need to make a 9th.

Answer (score 15):

An alternative to this problem,

> Anything left outside can be easily picked up by other player.

Place a fence around your turnips.

While someone is visiting your island, no one (including you) can pick up fences *(as well as "placed" things)*. This ensures no one will be able to get into your turnip field.

The only incredibly small caveat I can think of is that hackers may be able to no-clip through fences but the game itself may prevent anyone from picking up things in your house. But I think the chances of running into a hacker who wants to troll you like this is pretty small. Because if they are hacking they can already get as many bells as they want.

Comment: Another downside to this approach is that it would take up a TON of space that could otherwise be used for island development :/

Comment: @GammaGames Right, but putting it into your house means you can't decorate your house. Personally I'd like to leave my house like it is all the time instead of having to pick up furniture every Sunday. The turnips have to either be outside or inside and both places they prevent decorating. I've thought about dressing up my turnip patch with fancier walls and making a sign that says "Fort Stalx" like "Fort Knox", so there's ways you can mitigate the space needed.

Comment: good point, I always leave mine on some beach in the back of town because it's the easiest way to hide it

Comment: Another small note, Isabelle was mentioning lots of items laying around in my review and stopped after I sold them all. It didn't change the amount of stars but she did mention it

Comment: @CaptainMan that sounds to me like you’re implying that turnips aren’t decoration in themselves?

Comment: @RobinWhittleton To me they're a status symbol but Isabelle seems to disagree.